# Grid of options in CSS with flexible width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I can't seem to find a good way to do this, and Google hasn't helped much.
Basically, I have a UL with LI's, these LI all contain checkboxes with labels, each label can be of any length, and I want to present this in a table-like manner but flowing, so when the container width changes, the "grid" or table of items are reflowed to maintain the grid-like appearance. Here is an image that I hope explains:

[image]

See how the space for the "Small" in the first part is larger since the "Long option" won't fit, and then it does fit, the space for "Option" grows to the same size as the "Even longer option" to accommodate the new table/grid. And when all fit they all get their minimum size

So, just using flex these wouldn't line up. I am unsure whether "display: grid" could do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope not grid. I wouldn't normally recommend it but this looks like a job for FLOATS

Comment: It will be better if you share your code in a snippet to help understand more and edit it. Anyway, I think you can select each child in the grid and give 'min-width' so it will never go smaller than that when you change the container width.

Comment: Like @Paulie_D said, `grid` won't work. I'd explore `flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Comment: Please review my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75130718/15943900

Comment: OT: While an interesting problem, the grid here doesn't seem to have any purpose beyond aesthetics. Rather, it seems to waste space (as exemplified by the second image).

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it is not possible with CSS alone in the grid system. But as you have already done correctly with the Flexbox system.

**Why it doesn't work with grid?**

You can align the grid system by columns and rows. What you want to do would theoretically only work with row alignment. Definitely not with the column template. Because the column affects the width of the rows below.

Because you wants flexible divbox lengths that adjust to the varying widths of the entire column, it is not possible with the grid system. Now you can say, hey, then I'll do it at row level. Yes, but then you would not be able to make breaks. For this reason, it is right to do what you want to do with the flexbox system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr) ) ;
    color: #444;
  }
  .item {
    border: solid 1px #444;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<section class="item item1">Item 1</section>
<section class="item itemde">Item 1 Default</section>
<section class="item itemlt">Item 1 Longer than</section>
<section class="item itemltl">Item 1 longer than long</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your HTML like this as you describe

```
<ul class="con">
    <li>RICE</li>
    <li>BEANS</li>
    <li>PLANTAIN</li>
    <li>POTATO</li>
   <li>SUOP</li>
</ul>
```

Using Grid your CSS should be like so:

```
.con{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));   
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The grid set the minimum and maximum size of an item in the grid and then auto-fits it to the grid container

You can play around with the `minmax()` values

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box, like this

```css
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap
}
.item {
  background-color:red;
  margin:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<section class="item">Item 1</section>
<section class="item">Item 1 Default</section>
<section class="item">Item 1 Longer than</section>
<section class="item">Item 1 longer than long</section>
</div>
```

is this not what you are looking for?
Here is with ul,Li : https://jsfiddle.net/gk0by3uj/1/

Comment: If this is not what you want also , you have to use Javascript to get and compare the Width of each Item

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   margin: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: 0;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr) ) ;
   color: #444;
}
.item {
   border: solid 1px #444;
   padding: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

Try this by adding to your wrapper class in div and body.

Answer (score -1):

(This took two hours lol, really hoping it does the trick)

[Here's the source I primarily used for help formatting the code.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)

Try;

```js
function opt() {
  document.getElementById("1").style.color = "#B1B1B1";
}

function sml() {
  document.getElementById("2").style.color = "#B1B1B1";
}

function lng() {
  document.getElementById("3").style.color = "#B1B1B1";
}

function vlng() {
  document.getElementById("4").style.color = "#B1B1B1";
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("1").style.color = "#000";
  document.getElementById("2").style.color = "#000";
  document.getElementById("3").style.color = "#000";
  document.getElementById("4").style.color = "#000";
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}

.button-div {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-div button {
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="1" onclick="opt()">Option</div>
  <div id="2" onclick="sml()">Small</div>
  <div id="3" onclick="lng()">Long Option</div>
  <div id="4" onclick="vlng()">Even Longer Option</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="button-div">
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```